# Loading file into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've tried to way I was instructed and moved the code in csv I was given into the same folder as my Jupyter Notebook is located. It still isn't reading it. I'm also trying to convert it into a dataframe and get it to 'describe'. I'll post the code and the errors below. Please help! Thank you in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
fish = pd.read_csv('c:\\Users\\M\anaconda3\\Scripts\\Fish')

fish2 = pd.DataFrame(fish)

fish2.to_csv('fishdata.csv')

fish2.describe()
```

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11624/2289113011.py in <module>
----> 1 fish = pd.read_csv('c:\\Users\\M\anaconda3\\Scripts\\Fish')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    220         Let the readers open IOHandles after they are done with their potential raises.
    221         """
--> 222         self.handles = get_handle(
    223             src,
    224             "r",

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    699         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    700             # Encoding
--> 701             handle = open(
    702                 handle,
    703                 ioargs.mode,

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\Users\\M\x07naconda3\\Scripts\\Fish'
```

Comment: The read_csv function isn't actually reading a csv file from what it looks like. You need to correctly define the csv file path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename your file, append `.csv` to your file name

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the extension of the file, you are attempting to read.
For example: for csv file, your code can look like

```
fish = pd.read_csv('c:\\Users\\M\anaconda3\\Scripts\\Fish.csv')
```

Or if your file is in the same directory as your code, you can just use the full file name

```
fish = pd.read_csv('Fish.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly informed that the argument of `read_csv` is invalid.

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\Users\\M\x07naconda3\\Scripts\\Fish'
```

It seems you missed the cvs file, such as `table.csv`.

You can try to use `os.getcwd()` to check whether the current working directory is the same as the csv file.